# Choosing to use # vs class on a template page

Tags: html, css

I am building a new template page that allows my ecommerce store to be displayed via html.

I cannot decide whether to use ID or classes here. As it is a template they will only be referenced once. But it seems strange to put # to all the layout content to the right.

Below is my code, each line is a new division and I have tabbed to show child elements to the right and the parents to the left.

```
    <header></header>   <logo><cards><delivery><icons>
    <nav></nav>         <breadcrumb><navlinks>
    <aside></aside>     <category><search><manufacturers><whatsnew>
    <section></section> <maincontent>
    <aside></aside>     <cart><bestsellers><specials><reviews><information>
    <footer></footer>   
    <div></div>         <footerblock><worldpay><sslcert><paypal></footerblock>
```

Comment: you should use classes for sure, because you can recycle those properties elsewhere. id (#) can only be referred to once. for example, let's say you want to float: left; well you can call that class .left and reuse it in other elements on the html page

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using classes, even if you only use it once. If you decide later you want to reuse the styling of that element, you can easily apply the class. IDs are great if you have a long page of content and you want to provide shortcuts to sections (`<a href="#subsection">...</a>`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ID' reference in your template for development purpose and use 'Class' reference for styling purpose. Because later your application may extend for some purpose and in that time this template may reused (in the same page as well). In that time it needs lot of rework to change/apply different IDs for each place wherever the template used.

If you sure, it will not happen then you can use either ID or Class.

Note:

> A class can be used several times, while an ID can only be used once in a document.